# Is it possible to create a custom save & add products custom button with only custom fields for opportunities based on record types

Tags: salesforce

Scenario:

Clients need to capture some details before they save an opportunity record. I thought to customize the Product object but couldnt successfully customize that object as I couldnt remove required fields. So I want to create a custom button just like save & add products of opportunities.

Is it possible? Please help me in this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to override "Edit" button(since overriding "Save" is not possible) of Opportunity so that while saving it gets redirected to another page where I can get the values for that object